# Error upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

While I'm upgrading my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10 the following error is occurred in  distribution upgrade,

`W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources`

`404  Not Found

 E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead`

Does anybody know whats happening?

Comment: Maverick is not 12.04 is 10.10, why do you have the Maverick repositories enabled? did you upgraded from previous versions?

Comment: Yep, I've upgraded the maverick to 12.04. Please tell me how to disable the maverick repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Maverick is no longer supported. Remove references to maverick repositories from /etc/apt/sources.list and from files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/. Make sure that you still have references to quantal. After editing these files, run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the repositories and it's started to upgrade.